# How to filter a RecyclerView list in Fragment from SearchView in the Activity in Android?

Tags: android, filter, android-recyclerview, searchview

I am back again with me facing a real life issue again regarding an implementation in Android.

It is this, I have a Fragment in an Activity which displays a populated RecyclerView in the Fragment. Whereas, the Activity its in, has a SearchView.

Now, what I want is to filter the list in RecyclerView present in the fragment, based on text typed in the SearchView present in the Activity.

The question on my mind is how to implement this?

> A callback implementation? If so, how? If something else, how??

Guys! I am  in a bind. Please do let me know how to overcome this hurdle.

Counting on you guys! Awaits your positive and detailed response. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another recyclerview in the activity and in its adapter I implemented filterable and then passed the exact same data to its adapter as is in the fragment's adapter. It worked for me that way.

Answer (score 0):

You can see my realization of search [Mediateka](https://github.com/Devit951/Mediateka/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/ru/devit/mediateka/presentation/search)

Answer (score 0):

Write a function in the fragment say

```
 public void setSearchQuery(String query){
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(query)){
    yourAdapterItems=originalAdapterItems;
    nnotifyDataSetChanged();
    }else{
    copyOfAdapterItems=originalAdapterItems;
    yourAdapterItems=filter(copyOfAdapterItems,query);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    }
```

Now in the filter function, implement your logic for the filter

Add a textWatcher on your searchView and on the

```
void onTextChanged(...String query)
{
yourFragmentObjectReference.setSearchQuery(query);
}
```

Comment: I need the search query from the activity to correlate with adapter data in fragment

Comment: Yes, the first function goes in the fragment, but the second one goes in your activity, which with the reference of the fragment, will do the job